# When can a function be only called once?

Tags: javascript

This problem is giving me trouble:

> Write a function, once, (see: http://underscorejs.org/#once) that
>   takes a function and returns a version of that function which can only
>   be called once. [Hint: you need a closure] You probably don't want to
>   be able to double charge someone's credit card. Here is an example of
>   how to use it:

```
  var chargeCreditCard = function(num, price){
    //charges credit card for a certain price
  };
  var processPaymentOnce = once(chargeCreditCard);


  processPaymentOnce(123456789012, 200);
```

Here's how I tried to solve it:

```
var once = function(func) {
    var invoked = 0;
    return function() {
        if (invoked === 0) {
            invoked++;
            return func();
        } 
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I can see is you are not passing the arguments to the called function. You can use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object and [Function.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to do this.

```
var once = function (func) {
    var invoked = 0;
    return function () {
        if (invoked === 0) {
            invoked++;
            return func.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sr7haaeL/)

Comment: It also makes sense to replace a counter with a flag. For the given task it's more semantically correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost in the right path but you could also store the return value, pass the args and provide the `this` context:

```
function once(func) {
  var val,
    count = 2;
  return function () {
    if (--count > 0) {
      val = func.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      //performance concern
      func = null;
    }
    return val;
  };
}
```

This is what I have borrowed from [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to use in my codebase.

It is also worth noting that, passing the `count` variable as an argument would also let us to use it in a way that the `func` gets called less than `count` times

Comment: `//performance concern` --- what does this exactly mean? It also is reasonable and fair to give the credits for the source you taken this implementation from.

Comment: @zerkms this is the way we could clear the extra references to our objects which in this case is a function, considering the fact that extra references will prevent the object from getting removed from the memory.

Comment: Thank you, Mehran for the help!  zerkms is a very cranky and rude person.  I wouldn't pay him any mind.

Comment: @RoryPerro it's not "help" actually - you know no more than you did before. You will copy paste the provided solution but next time when you have something similar but not exactly the same - you'll be in stuck.

Comment: I don't consider @zerkms 's comment as a rude comment. He is right. [lodash](https://lodash.com/)  is the source we should give it the actual credit. And as he pointed out I have mentioned the link in the answer. But the point is we are all here to help each other. This is our community and I like it anyway.

Comment: @zerkms I'm here to learn.  I wish you would teach me something, instead of making snide comments all the time.

Comment: @RoryPerro there were no snide comments until you started it. I've given a serious advice to start with something simpler. There is nothing wrong in not knowing something. But it's not efficient to start with something that is too complicated. You don't start learning maths with integrals, but with addition and subtraction.

Comment: @zerkms I'm very comfortable with JS fundamentals, and I'm ready for a problem like this.  And still, with all the words you've written in this post, you haven't said one thing that is helpful. You're a small king in your tiny kingdom. You like to look down on newbies.  Fine, knock yourself out.  I'm still here to learn.

Comment: @RoryPerro "I'm very comfortable with JS fundamentals" "is this correct?" --- these 2 cannot be both true together. If one cannot run a function - they need to learn that first.